# What's the difference when not using the (,) in print statement with %

Tags: python-3.x

I've seen some statements about print like,

```
print('%d' % (b, ))
```

however, the output is the same when I implement this

```
print('%d' % b)
```

so what's the difference, can I just use the second one?

I am a beginner, thanks so much for helping.

Comment: @dpap totally unrelated actually

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers if you think so, then ok.

Comment: @dpap it's not about what _I_ personnaly "think" or not, it's just Python official syntax. The trailing comma in a py2.7 `print` statement has nothing to do with the trailing comma used to defined a "one-uple" (tuple of size 1).

Comment: ok then. i deleted it

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in in the outcome. But there is a difference in underlying mechanisms used. In the first case you are passing a Tuple. In the second - a Number. Comma is needed to specify you intention to pass exactly a Tuple.

Also you can pass:

```
print('%d' % (b))
```

This variant is equal to the second - (b) is interpreted as a Number.

Also worth to mention, this is old formatting mechanism. You can read more here:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting

But there is a newer one:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format

And even newer one (python3.6):

https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498

Comment: and there is an even newer newer one - [f strings](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html)

Comment: Thanks @MattB.! Mentioned this mechanism as well

Answer (score 0):

You have run into a corner case of handling of 1-length tuples in the case of old formatting. The end result of both is the same, because of how old `%` formatting handles 1 length tuples.

Also note that there is another issue at play as well, regarding python allowing trailing commas. I have talked about it more on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54399930/type1-returns-int-expected-tuple/54400165#54400165) but the gist is that python allows a quality of life trailing comma in arguments as well, which then leads to ambuigity with 1-length tuples that has to be resolved somehow.

> The issue lies in how python has to interpret function arguments,
>   while allowing the "quality of life" trailing comma. Functions are
>   called with parentheses with comma separated arguments. When you pass
>   type(1,), There is ambiguity between a comma separated argument with a
>   trailing comma, and an actual tuple.

The examples below should help make the distinction clearer.

```
one_number = 3 #creates an int object

one_item_tuple = (3,) #creates a 1 length tuple that contains an int object

type(one_item_tuple)
Out[3]: tuple

one_item_tuple[0] == one_number
Out[4]: True

print("%d hello" % one_number)
3 hello

print("%d hello" % one_item_tuple) #here is the edge case behaviour.
3 hello
```

Note that you should really be using the newer formatting tools. formatting strings using `%` is a very outdated method.

You can use [`.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)

```
print("{} hello".format(one_number))
3 hello

print("{} hello".format(one_item_tuple)) #more obvious and graceful with tuples
(3,) hello

print("{} hello".format(3,)) #but this runs into the 1-argument with trailing comma vs 1 length tuple ambuigity corner case
3 hello
```

Or [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) after python 3.6

```
print(f"{one_number} hello")
3 hello

print(f"{one_item_tuple} hello")
(3,) hello

print(f"{3,} hello") #robust even in this case, because it has to interpret the contents inside `{}` first
(3,) hello
```